# Create sample Azure Hadoop job via Web UI or cross-platform CLI?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to play with Hadoop on Azure using HDInsight, but am a bit confused on how to run a Hadoop job on my newly created cluster.  So far I've created an HDInsight cluster and attached a Storage Account to it.  I also have the azure-cli installed on my local OS X box.

There's an Azure [tutorial on launching Hadoop jobs](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/), but it uses PowerShell, which I don't think is available via the [Azure cross-platform CLI](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/install-and-configure-cli/).

Aside form starting up a Windows VirtualBox, can a job get created via the Azure Web UI (e.g. like Amazon EMR provides) or via some other command line arguments that would be compatible with OS X?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Login using Remote Desktop Protocol into the head node of the cluster and use CLI tools there.
2. Or submit jobs using [WebHCatalog REST APIs](http://hive.apache.org/docs/hcat_r0.5.0/rest.html) (e.g. using curl).

HDInsight currently has [XPlat CLI tools for cluster provisioning](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/administer-hdinsight-using-command-line-interface/). Job submission XPlat CLI tools will be available later.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if WebHCatalog is only for Hive, or can standard Jar jobs be submitted?

Comment: The first link you provided (WebHCatalog REST APIs) is broken.